# How do I implement the delete functionality as mentioned below?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

[Delete functionality here when you click the delete icon](https://react-advanced-assignment.psamd.vercel.app/)

Hi, how do I implement a similar delete functionality as from the link above?

I have attached my code below for your guys' reference, I'm using a map method to grab the data from an array of an object which is then transferred to props.

App.js file

```
import logo from "./logo.svg";
import "./App.css";
import IndividualContact from "./Components/IndividualContact";
import ContactList from "./Components/ContactList";
import EditDetails from "./Components/EditDetails";
import { useState } from "react";

const CONTACT_DATA = [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: "Leanne Graham",
    username: "Bret",
    email: "Sincere@april.biz",
    address: {
      street: "Kulas Light",
      suite: "Apt. 556",
      city: "Gwenborough",
      zipcode: "92998-3874",
      geo: {
        lat: "-37.3159",
        lng: "81.1496",
      },
    },
    phone: "1-770-736-8031 x56442",
    website: "hildegard.org",
    company: {
      name: "Romaguera-Crona",
      catchPhrase: "Multi-layered client-server neural-net",
      bs: "harness real-time e-markets",
    },
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: "Ervin Howell",
    username: "Antonette",
    email: "Shanna@melissa.tv",
    address: {
      street: "Victor Plains",
      suite: "Suite 879",
      city: "Wisokyburgh",
      zipcode: "90566-7771",
      geo: {
        lat: "-43.9509",
        lng: "-34.4618",
      },
    },
    phone: "010-692-6593 x09125",
    website: "anastasia.net",
    company: {
      name: "Deckow-Crist",
      catchPhrase: "Proactive didactic contingency",
      bs: "synergize scalable supply-chains",
    },
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    name: "Clementine Bauch",
    username: "Samantha",
    email: "Nathan@yesenia.net",
    address: {
      street: "Douglas Extension",
      suite: "Suite 847",
      city: "McKenziehaven",
      zipcode: "59590-4157",
      geo: {
        lat: "-68.6102",
        lng: "-47.0653",
      },
    },
    phone: "1-463-123-4447",
    website: "ramiro.info",
    company: {
      name: "Romaguera-Jacobson",
      catchPhrase: "Face to face bifurcated interface",
      bs: "e-enable strategic applications",
    },
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    name: "Patricia Lebsack",
    username: "Karianne",
    email: "Julianne.OConner@kory.org",
    address: {
      street: "Hoeger Mall",
      suite: "Apt. 692",
      city: "South Elvis",
      zipcode: "53919-4257",
      geo: {
        lat: "29.4572",
        lng: "-164.2990",
      },
    },
    phone: "493-170-9623 x156",
    website: "kale.biz",
    company: {
      name: "Robel-Corkery",
      catchPhrase: "Multi-tiered zero tolerance productivity",
      bs: "transition cutting-edge web services",
    },
  },
  {
    id: 5,
    name: "Chelsey Dietrich",
    username: "Kamren",
    email: "Lucio_Hettinger@annie.ca",
    address: {
      street: "Skiles Walks",
      suite: "Suite 351",
      city: "Roscoeview",
      zipcode: "33263",
      geo: {
        lat: "-31.8129",
        lng: "62.5342",
      },
    },
    phone: "(254)954-1289",
    website: "demarco.info",
    company: {
      name: "Keebler LLC",
      catchPhrase: "User-centric fault-tolerant solution",
      bs: "revolutionize end-to-end systems",
    },
  },
  {
    id: 6,
    name: "Mrs. Dennis Schulist",
    username: "Leopoldo_Corkery",
    email: "Karley_Dach@jasper.info",
    address: {
      street: "Norberto Crossing",
      suite: "Apt. 950",
      city: "South Christy",
      zipcode: "23505-1337",
      geo: {
        lat: "-71.4197",
        lng: "71.7478",
      },
    },
    phone: "1-477-935-8478 x6430",
    website: "ola.org",
    company: {
      name: "Considine-Lockman",
      catchPhrase: "Synchronised bottom-line interface",
      bs: "e-enable innovative applications",
    },
  },
  {
    id: 7,
    name: "Kurtis Weissnat",
    username: "Elwyn.Skiles",
    email: "Telly.Hoeger@billy.biz",
    address: {
      street: "Rex Trail",
      suite: "Suite 280",
      city: "Howemouth",
      zipcode: "58804-1099",
      geo: {
        lat: "24.8918",
        lng: "21.8984",
      },
    },
    phone: "210.067.6132",
    website: "elvis.io",
    company: {
      name: "Johns Group",
      catchPhrase: "Configurable multimedia task-force",
      bs: "generate enterprise e-tailers",
    },
  },
  {
    id: 8,
    name: "Nicholas Runolfsdottir V",
    username: "Maxime_Nienow",
    email: "Sherwood@rosamond.me",
    address: {
      street: "Ellsworth Summit",
      suite: "Suite 729",
      city: "Aliyaview",
      zipcode: "45169",
      geo: {
        lat: "-14.3990",
        lng: "-120.7677",
      },
    },
    phone: "586.493.6943 x140",
    website: "jacynthe.com",
    company: {
      name: "Abernathy Group",
      catchPhrase: "Implemented secondary concept",
      bs: "e-enable extensible e-tailers",
    },
  },
  {
    id: 9,
    name: "Glenna Reichert",
    username: "Delphine",
    email: "Chaim_McDermott@dana.io",
    address: {
      street: "Dayna Park",
      suite: "Suite 449",
      city: "Bartholomebury",
      zipcode: "76495-3109",
      geo: {
        lat: "24.6463",
        lng: "-168.8889",
      },
    },
    phone: "(775)976-6794 x41206",
    website: "conrad.com",
    company: {
      name: "Yost and Sons",
      catchPhrase: "Switchable contextually-based project",
      bs: "aggregate real-time technologies",
    },
  },
  {
    id: 10,
    name: "Clementina DuBuque",
    username: "Moriah.Stanton",
    email: "Rey.Padberg@karina.biz",
    address: {
      street: "Kattie Turnpike",
      suite: "Suite 198",
      city: "Lebsackbury",
      zipcode: "31428-2261",
      geo: {
        lat: "-38.2386",
        lng: "57.2232",
      },
    },
    phone: "024-648-3804",
    website: "ambrose.net",
    company: {
      name: "Hoeger LLC",
      catchPhrase: "Centralized empowering task-force",
      bs: "target end-to-end models",
    },
  },
];

function App() {
  const [showEditDetails, setShowEditDetails] = useState(false);

  const showEditHandlder = () =>{
    setShowEditDetails(true);
  }

  const closeEditHandlder = () => {
    setShowEditDetails(false);
  }
  return (
    <div className="App">
      {showEditDetails && (
        <EditDetails onClose={closeEditHandlder} contactData={CONTACT_DATA}></EditDetails>
      )}
      <ContactList onShow={showEditHandlder}  contactData={CONTACT_DATA}></ContactList>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

ContactList.js file

```
import React from 'react'
import IndividualContact from './IndividualContact'

export default function ContactList(props) {
  return (
    <div className="row g-4">

        {props.contactData.map((x) => (
        <IndividualContact 
        onShow={props.onShow}
        name={x.name}
        email={x.email}
        website={x.website}
        phone={x.phone}
        username={x.username}
        ></IndividualContact>

        ))}
    </div>
  )
}
```

IndividualContact.js file

```
import React from "react";
import { useState } from "react";
import "./IndividualContact.css";
import {
  MailOutlined,
  PhoneOutlined,
  GlobalOutlined,
  HeartOutlined,
  EditOutlined,
  DeleteOutlined,
  HeartFilled,
} from "@ant-design/icons";

export default function IndividualContactRow(props) {
  const [ifLiked, setIfLiked] = useState(false);
  const clickHandler = () => {
    setIfLiked(!ifLiked);
  };
  return (
    <div className=" col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-xl-3 col-3">
      <div className="container-test">
        <div className="body-image">
          <img
            src={`https://avatars.dicebear.com/v2/avataaars/${props.username}.svg?options[mood][]=happy`}
          ></img>
        </div>
        <div className="body-content">
          <h3>{props.name}</h3>
          <div className="d-flex flex-row">
            <MailOutlined style={{ fontSize: "18px", height: "26px" }} />
            <p>{props.email}</p>
          </div>
          <div className="d-flex flex-row">
            <PhoneOutlined style={{ fontSize: "18px", height: "26px" }} />
            <p>{props.phone}</p>
          </div>
          <div className="d-flex flex-row">
            <GlobalOutlined style={{ fontSize: "18px", height: "26px" }} />
            <p>{  `http://${props.website}`}</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <ul className="body-actions">
          <li>
            <button onClick={clickHandler}>
              {ifLiked && <HeartFilled style={{ color: "red", fontSize: "20px" }}></HeartFilled>}
              {!ifLiked && (
                <HeartOutlined style={{ color: "red", fontSize: "20px" }} />
              )}{" "}
            </button>
          </li>

          <li>
            <button>
              {" "}
              <EditOutlined onClick={props.onShow} style={{ fontSize: "20px" }}></EditOutlined>
            </button>
          </li>

          <li>
            <button>
              {" "}
              <DeleteOutlined style={{ fontSize: "20px" }}></DeleteOutlined>
            </button>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Make the contact data a state array instead of passing the constant. Then on a delete button click, use filter() to create a copy of the array without the deleted element and set that as the new state array.

Comment: @ChrisG but how do I pass that which specific item needs to be deleted?

Comment: You use the id of the person, and pass it along to the delete handler function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In App.js, create a local state which holds the list of users

```
const [contacts, setContacts] = useState(CONTACT_DATA);
```

Also create a method in App.js  for deleting the data which will accept contact id as argument.

```
const deleteContact = (id) => {
   const tmpContacts = contacts.filter((contact) => contact.id != id);
   setContacts([...tmpContacts]);
}
```

Now instead of passing **CONTACT_DATA** as the prop in ContactList component, pass the **contacts** state variable. Also pass the newly created method **deleteContact**.

```
<ContactList onShow={showEditHandlder}  contactData={contacts} onDelete={deleteContact}></ContactList>
```

Now in ContactList component, pass this to IndividualContact component

```
<IndividualContact 
        onShow={props.onShow}
        name={x.name}
        email={x.email}
        website={x.website}
        phone={x.phone}
        username={x.username}
        onDelete={props.onDelete}
        ></IndividualContact>
```

Finally, hook this onDelete method to the delete button in Individual contact component.

```
<button onClick={(e) => props.onDelete(props.id)}>
   <DeleteOutlined style={{ fontSize: "20px" }}></DeleteOutlined>
</button>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot man, coincidentally I thought of the same solution but you structured the entire thing for me, much appreciated!

Comment: `setContacts([...tmpContacts]);` is not necessary, you can use `setContacts(tmpContacts);` instead (it's already a shallow copy)